# Replacing a word ignoring spaces and cases from a string in Android

Tags: android, string, replace

What I'm trying to do:
if a String is

```
String a = "Love is rare"; Or
String a = "l o v e is rare"; Or
String a = "LO VE is rare";
```

Then,
I want the word "love" to be replaced by "hate" ignoring the space and case

My code: 
`a=a.toLowerCase().replace("love","hate").replace("\\s+","");`

But the problem is that it removes all the spaces and change all the words to lower case. I just want to check if there is a word love by ignoring all the spaces and cases and if the word is there then replace it with some other word.

Please help! 
Thank you.

Comment: Could be accomplished with case-insensitive regex. Then use a capture group to replace the match with your target value. `(l\s*o\s*v\s*e)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for suggesting the term regex, Studied thoroughly and come up with this one line function which will replace "love" by "hate" ignoring the spaces and cases:

```
String a = "Lo ve is rare.";
```

Code:

```
a = a.replaceAll("(?i)l(\\s*)o(\\s*)v(\\s*)e","hate");
TextView.setText(a);
```

This would give:

```
hate is rare.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this using an optional whitespace `?` and the case insensitive flag. If you want to match zero or more whitespaces, you could use a whitespace and *

[`l ?o ?v ?e`](https://regex101.com/r/oFICwa/1)

```
String regex = "l ?o ?v ?e";
String[] lines = {"Love is rare", "l o v e is rare", "LO VE is rare"};
String subst = "hate";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

for (String line: lines) { 
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

That would give you:

```
hate is rare
hate is rare
hate is rare
```

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/PCSKT57550)